# hook_page_attachments() not called from mytheme.theme file

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to load an asset library in my Drupal 8 custom theme. I have created the library and can load it via mytheme.info.yml file.  However, if I try the load it using hook_page_attachments() in the mytheme.theme file, then the function is not called.

I did a search for this function in the Drupal 8 standard installation and it only ever seems to be called from modules.  Can hook_page_attachments only be called from modules? Any suggestions on why this is not working.

mytheme.theme file content:

```
function mytheme_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments ['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/general-js';
}
```

Answer (score 11):

It appears that this function is only callable from a module, as it is listed in  [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843) but not listed as a valid method in [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195).

It should be noted that the related function [hook_page_attachments_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8) can be called from the theme layer (i.e. can be called from mytheme.theme file).

```
function mytheme_page_attachments_alter(&$page) {
  $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/general-js';
}
```

Alternatively one can attach libraries to a page from within hook_preprocess_page()

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/cuddly-slider';
}
```

The advantage of these two methods is that it enables one to utilize logic/code to determine whether or not to attach a library to a page.

Comment: Another bennefit of using these methods is attaching inline scripts to the head of a page. For example, the "advanced" typekit script, or a google analytics script you want to manually code in. Good instructions on how to here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2642476#comment-11838322

Comment: A bit misleading, that `hook_page_attachments` is placed in theme.api.php: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.2.x