# What is the proper way to add third party script snippets to head tag?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

I understand I can hard-code this snippet into html.html.twig but i would prefer a cleaner method. My research is only instructing me how to attach libraries etc, but I can't find any example of injecting code into the header area needed by some third-party services.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function THEME_page_attachments(&$page) {
  /**
   * Initial JS.
   */
  $javascript_header = "-----js code -----";

  $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    // The data.
    [
      // Add a <script> tag.
      '#tag' => 'script',
      // Add JavaScript to the <script> tag.
      '#value' => \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create($javascript_header),
      // Give weight so it appears after meta tags, etc.
      '#weight' => -1,
    ],

    'key'
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems to be related with [hook_page_attachments() not called from mytheme.theme file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/147365/hook-page-attachments-not-called-from-mytheme-theme-file). If you look to the answer, it's written -

> It appears that this function is only callable from a module, as it is
>   listed in [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8
>   module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843) but not listed as a valid method in [Adding stylesheets (CSS)
>   and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195).

I verified with the current documentation & that's correct. You can use [hook_page_attachments_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.2.x), which has documented in above given document for **Adding stylesheets and JS to a Drupal 8 theme**.

Comment: Yes indeed. My code above works once I add alter to the function. Thank you.

Comment: how to render the script tag within body tag?