# Can you override a library per environment?

Tags: 8, javascript

In my libraries.yml file, I have something like this, being used to define "foo-bar" as a library that can be pulled in from various parts of the site:

```
foo-bar:
  version: 0.0.x
  js:
    js/foo-dev.js: {}
```

This works well on my local environment, but on our production and QA environments, I would like for it to look more like this:

```
foo-bar:
  version: 0.0.x
  js:
    js/foo-prod.js: {}
```

(The prod version will include optimizations that normally don't appear with minification alone).

Currently, we are using the sites/<site>/settings.*.php files and the config-split module to have different configurations based on the environment, but is there a way to have the foo-bar library reference the dev-friendly version on one environment, and the production version on all others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to override paths defined in \*.libraries.yml](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210959/is-there-a-way-to-override-paths-defined-in-libraries-yml)

Answer (score 4):

Look at [`hook_page_attachments`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.2.x). In the sample snippet provided behind that link there is a simple if-request which attaches a certain library only when a certain condition is met. Do the same.

**MYTHEME/MYMODULE.libraries.yml**

```
foo-bar-dev:
  version: 0.0.x
  js:
    js/foo-dev.js: {}
foo-bar-prod:
  version: 0.0.x
  js:
    js/foo-prod.js: {}
```

**MYTHEME.theme/MYMODULE.module**

```
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {

  // Conditionally attach an asset to the page.
  if (\Drupal::request()->getHost() == 'example.com') {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'MYTHEME/MYMODULE/foo-bar-prod';
  }
  else {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'MYTHEME/MYMODULE/foo-bar-dev';
  }
}
```

---

More info on base URL: [how to get base url of a site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/202810/15055).

Comment: If you have attached the library already in other places and therefore want to keep the library name you could use `hook_library_info_alter` to alter only the js file name.

Comment: @4k4 – Gosh, you are so right. Found my own question when googling named hook: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/210959/15055

Comment: As noted [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/147366/3167)  if you want to put this logic in a theme, you cannot use `hook_page_attachments()` but can use [`hook_page_attachments_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/hook_page_attachments_alter) or `hook_preprocess_page`.